# Ending letters with ~~よりご多幸を祈って

Tags: formality

This phrase showed up in one my phrase books with the translation of "Best Wishes" but I'm curious if it can be used to sign off letters and emails with the same casual politeness that the phrase carries in English.

Comment: I see in correspondence context the phrase means "with best wishes". Literally, a "XXXよりご多幸を祈って" means "from/by XXX with hope for best things (物事を行う人の成功や安全などを願う表現).

Answer (score 1):

I think it will sound oddly formal for email, but it would be natural for snail mails (they tend to be more formally written than email).